# Get iBeacon UUID Radius Network Library

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I've downloaded the non pro version of the Radius Networks iBeacon Android Library and I have run the sample code from their site [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html) and all works well.  However, rather than creating a new region, I want to be able to get the ibeacon data -- uuid, major, minor etc...

So I downloaded the github library and looked through it, however at the moment I'm unable to get the data broadcasting from my beacon...I have bound the iBeaconService to my activity and I'm unsure where to go from here...if anyone can help i'd greatly appreciate it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a region with a null UUID, major and minor and then range for all iBeacons in this region.  This will detect all iBeacons within radio range and give you all of their identifiers.

Here is an example class that does exactly what is described above:

https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-reference/blob/master/src/com/radiusnetworks/ibeaconreference/RangingActivity.java

Comment: excellent, thank you for your speedy response, however, if I try create a region with a null UUID I get a crash "  java.lang.NullPointerException: uniqueId may not be null
            at com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.Region.<init>(Region.java:77)"

Comment: sorry I actually set it to new Region(null, null, null, null)...so I just put a default string in...Thanks again!